# Bitbucket / Mercurial: Test pull request before merging

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket, pull-request

We are using Mercurial on Bitbucket.

Someone from my team just cloned the main repository into his own private one. He created a pull request and I must integrated that into the main repository.

How can I first test the things in the pull request before integrating into the main repository. I found a [solution](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bbkb/how-to-locally-fetch-and-checkout-a-pull-request-724402529.html) but it's for Git on Bitbucket.

[UPDATE]
The screenshot that shows that for Mercurial the interface does not provide the proper link for pull/update. It only shows a tooltip.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that right now (Sept 13, 2016) on Bitbucket if someone privately forked your mercurial repository and created a pull request you (the owner of original repository) will not be able to pull changes from that pull request and THEN to update your repository.

I think it's because the private fork deny you access to the URL you were suppose to get changes.

For now I solved it by asking access to the private fork.

Answer (score 0):

1. Both VCS use the same (Bitbucket's, not SCM-specific) idea of special URLs for PullRequests
2. Git-solution can be easy adopted to Hg by replacing Git-lingua (and entities) by corresponding Hg equivalents. Namely:

   - p.1 - as is
   - p.2-3 - `hg pull URL/OF/PR` (or `pull -u` if needed /you haven't THG or `postpull = update` in THG/)

as result you'll get *diverged history tree* added to your repo (as anonymous branch to you mainline or new named branch) and new `tip` will point to the topmost changeset in PR, which you can check|inspect|test

Comment: I updated the question with a screenshot that shows that the URL is not presented in the status bar as they say in the tutorial/guide.

Comment: @Alex - see https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/work-with-pull-requests-223220593.html#Workwithpullrequests-Mercurialcommandlineexample

Comment: I know what commands to use but it seems that if the fork is private you have now URL (nor is that URL accessible) as least for Mercurial repositories.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and, based on information retrieved from [here](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/8323/add-link-for-raw-patch-to-pull-request-ui#comment-6590315), there is a possible workaround. You download the PR as a patch and then apply it locally:

```
curl -u [user]:[password] https://bitbucket.org/api/2.0/repositories/[group]/[project]/pullrequests/[number]/patch -L -o pr.patch
hg import pr.patch --no-commit
```

Not the ideal solution, but it may do the job for some use cases.